# Solidity Smart Contract & Hedera Hashgraph Javascript SDK Integration

Tags: javascript, solidity, smartcontracts, hedera-hashgraph

I am dealing with an issue with a codebase that was previously working fine, but now it's not working as expected.

**Context**
The Smart Contract  `JobPost` provides a decentralized platform for job postings, allowing users to create, update, and retrieve job listings. It introduces two events, JobPostCreated and JobPostUpdated, to emit notifications upon job creation and updates, enhancing the contract's transparency and providing hooks for off-chain applications to react to these changes.

The Hashgraph Javascript script:
The JavaScript code interacts with the Hedera network to deploy and interact with the JobPost contract.

**The Issue**
My issue is that when I try to post a new job, it says that the job was successfully created, but whenever I try to fetch the javascript code, it returns an empty element, meaning that it seems like the job was not successfully posted to the blockchain with its parameters.

**Snippets of the source code**

Smart contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract JobPost {
    struct Job {
        uint256 jobId;
        string jobTitle;
        string paymentMethod;
        string accountId;
        address account;
    }

    enum paymentMethods {
        CASH,
        DEBIT,
        CREDIT,
        CRYPTO
    }

    event JobPostCreated(
        uint256 jobId,
        string jobTitle,
        string paymentMethod,
        string accountId,
        address account
    );

    event JobPostUpdated(
        uint256 _jobId,
        string _jobTitle,
        string _paymentMethod,
        address _account,
        string _accountId
    );

    // mapping(uint => Job) JobsByIndex;
    mapping(address => Job[]) JobsByAccount;
    uint256 public jobCounter = 0;

    constructor() {}

    function newJobPostByAccount(
        string memory _jobTitle,
        string memory _paymentMethod,
        string memory _accountId
    ) public {
        jobCounter++;
        JobsByAccount[msg.sender].push(
            Job({
                jobId: jobCounter,
                jobTitle: _jobTitle,
                paymentMethod: _paymentMethod,
                accountId: _accountId,
                account: msg.sender
            })
        );

        emit JobPostCreated(
            jobCounter,
            _jobTitle,
            _paymentMethod,
            _accountId,
            msg.sender
        );
    }

    function getOneJobPostByAccount2(
        address _account,
        uint256 _jobId
    )
        public
        view
        returns (
            address account,
            string memory accountId,
            uint256 jobId,
            string memory jobTitle,
            string memory paymentMethod
        )
    {
        // require(_account <= jobCounter);
        Job[] storage jobs = JobsByAccount[_account];
        for (uint256 index = 0; index < jobs.length; index++) {
            if (jobs[index].jobId == _jobId) {
                return (
                    jobs[index].account,
                    jobs[index].accountId,
                    jobs[index].jobId,
                    jobs[index].jobTitle,
                    jobs[index].paymentMethod
                );
            }
        }
    }

    function getOneJobPostByAccount(
        address _account,
        uint256 _jobId
    ) public view returns (Job memory job) {
        // require(_account <= jobCounter);
        Job[] storage jobs = JobsByAccount[_account];
        for (uint256 index = 0; index < jobs.length; index++) {
            if (jobs[index].jobId == _jobId) {
                return (jobs[index]);
            }
        }
        // return (0,"","",0x0);
    }

    function updateJobPostByAccount(
        uint256 _jobId,
        string memory _jobTitle,
        string memory _paymentMethod,
        address _account,
        string memory _accountId
    ) public {
        Job[] storage jobs = JobsByAccount[_account];
        require(_jobId <= jobCounter);
        // require(jobs, "This user does not exist");
        require(jobs.length > 0, "No Job post exists for this user");
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < jobs.length; i++) {
            if (jobs[i].jobId == _jobId) {
                jobs[i].jobTitle = _jobTitle;
                jobs[i].paymentMethod = _paymentMethod;
                jobs[i].account = _account;
                jobs[i].accountId = _accountId;
            }
        }
        emit JobPostUpdated(
            _jobId,
            _jobTitle,
            _paymentMethod,
            _account,
            _accountId
        );
    }

    function getAllJobsByAccount(
        address _account
    ) public view returns (Job[] memory) {
        Job[] storage jobs = JobsByAccount[_account];
        // require(jobs.length > 0, "No Job post exists for this user");
        if (jobs.length > 0) {
            return jobs;
        } else {
            Job[] memory emptyJobs;
            return emptyJobs;
        }
    }
}
```

Javascript Code

```
console.clear();
require("dotenv").config({ path: "../.env" });

const {
  Client,
  AccountId,
  PrivateKey,
  Hbar,
  FileCreateTransaction,
  FileAppendTransaction,
  ContractCallQuery,
  ContractCreateTransaction,
  ContractFunctionParameters,
  ContractExecuteTransaction,
} = require("@hashgraph/sdk");
const fs = require("fs");

const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3();

// console.log(process.env.HEDERA_ACCOUNT_ID);
const operatorId = process.env.HEDERA_ACCOUNT_ID;
const operatorKey = PrivateKey.fromStringECDSA(process.env.HEDERA_PRIVATE_KEY);

const bytecode = require("../build/contracts/JobPost.json", "utf8").bytecode;
const abi = require("../build/contracts/JobPost.json", "utf8").abi;
let bytecodeFileId;

const client = Client.forTestnet().setOperator(operatorId, operatorKey);

// Deploy the smart Contract to Hedera (createContractBytecodeFileId + uploadByteCode + instantiateContract)
await deploySmartContract(client, operatorKey, bytecode, 3000000, 10);

// Create a New Job Post
await newJobPostByAccount(
  client,
  contractId,
  operatorId,
  "Job Post #1",
  "CASH"
);

// Get One Job Post By Account
await getOneJobPostByAccount2(
  client,
  "getOneJobPostByAccount2",
  contractId,
  operatorId,
  2
);

async function newJobPostByAccount(
  _client,
  _contractId,
  _accountId,
  _title,
  _paymentMethod,
  _gas = 3000000
) {
  const contractExecTx = await new ContractExecuteTransaction()
    .setContractId(_contractId)
    .setGas(_gas)
    .setFunction(
      "newJobPostByAccount",
      new ContractFunctionParameters()
        .addString(_title)
        .addString(_paymentMethod)
        .addString(_accountId)
    );
  const contractExecSubmit = await contractExecTx.execute(_client);
  const contractExecRx = await contractExecSubmit.getReceipt(_client);
  console.log(contractExecRx);
  console.log(`\nCREATING A NEW JOB POST ======= \n`);
  console.log(`- New Job Post Created: ${contractExecRx.status.toString()}`);
  console.log(`\nRETRIEVE A JOB POST BY ACCOUNT ======= \n`);
}

async function decodeFunctionResult(functionName, resultAsBytes) {
  const functionAbi = abi.find(
    (func) => func.name === functionName && func.type === "function"
  );
  const functionParameters = functionAbi.outputs;
  const resultHex = "0x".concat(Buffer.from(resultAsBytes).toString("hex"));
  const result = await web3.eth.abi.decodeParameters(
    functionParameters,
    resultHex
  );
  return result;
}

async function getOneJobPostByAccount2(
  _client,
  _functionName,
  _contractId,
  _accountId,
  _jobId,
  _gas = 100000,
  _queryPaymentInHBars = 2
) {
  const contractQuery = await new ContractCallQuery()
    //Set the gas for the query
    .setGas(_gas)
    //Set the contract ID to return the request for
    .setContractId(_contractId)
    //Set the contract function to call
    .setFunction(
      _functionName,
      new ContractFunctionParameters()
        .addAddress(AccountId.fromString(_accountId).toSolidityAddress())
        .addUint256(_jobId)
    )
    //Set the query payment for the node returning the request
    //This value must cover the cost of the request otherwise will fail
    .setQueryPayment(new Hbar(_queryPaymentInHBars));

  //Submit to a Hedera network
  const contractExec = await contractQuery.execute(_client);
  // console.log(contractExec);
  console.log(`\nRETRIEVE A JOB POST BY ACCOUNT ======= \n`);
  console.log(
    `- New Job Post Account Owner: ${await contractExec.getString(0)}`
  );
  // console.log(`- New Job Post Created2: ${await contractExec.getString(1)}`)
  console.log(`- New Job Post Title: ${await contractExec.getString(2)}`);
  console.log(
    `- New Job Post Payment Method: ${await contractExec.getString(3)}`
  );
  const res = await decodeFunctionResult(_functionName, contractExec.bytes);
  console.log(res[0]);
  return res[0];
}
```

**Console Output**

Below is the link to the deployed contract and what my console is outputting

https://hashscan.io/testnet/contract/0.0.3767523

[image]

Comment: I tested the contract with Remix, and it works as expected; for example, I'm able to retrieve the information using `0xdfad8138e04c7932c26c0a37d3711fa9165704f1` and `1` or `2` as the jobId parameter, or `0xe0b73f64b0de6032b193648c08899f20b5a6141d` and `3` as the jobId (the job post I submitted).

Comment: The problem seems in the Javascript code; particularly it can be in the conversion between the account ID and the EVM address (check if `AccountId.fromString(_accountId).toSolidityAddress()` returns `0xdfad8138e04c7932c26c0a37d3711fa9165704f1` in your case, or in the decoding of the return values: it is possible the web3 version you are using (what version is it?) is not able to decode ABIEncoderV2 yet. Try printing the `contractExec` object, so we can check if it contains something. Let me know :)

Comment: @GiuseppeBertone. I have tried everything mane. Nothing is working. Can I send you my entire javascript code and smart contract for you to take a look at? I am so desperate, bro. This issue has been lagging for 2 weeks now, since I started working on it again. Please help me bro

Comment: Sure, no problem. It would be easier to check and fix it if you post the entire repo on GitHub (Gitlab, or similar). Just remember to update the question also with the new details.

Comment: BTW, 99% the problem is the usage of `AccountId.fromString(_accountId).toSolidityAddress()`. I think if you change that with your EVM address (`0xdfad8138e04c7932c26c0a37d3711fa9165704f1`) it should work as expected. `toSolidityAddress` function can be misleading because it works only for non-EVM native account, converting the account id into hex (like this for example: https://hashscan.io/testnet/account/0.0.3774165 note the many zeros in the EVM address). In your case you are using an EVM native account instead, so that function will not be able to return your actual address.

Comment: @GiuseppeBertone. You are a genius mane. You were right.

Comment: Cool, happy we managed to solve this. I'll prepare an answer from our discussion, so also others can avoid this pitfall. It would also be useful to add a warning in the SDK about that function, I'll open a Github issue about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the usage of `AccountId.fromString(_accountId).toSolidityAddress()`. The JavaScript code will work as expected if you change it with your actual EVM address (`0xdfad8138e04c7932c26c0a37d3711fa9165704f1`).

The `toSolidityAddress()` function is [static and does not access the network](https://github.com/hashgraph/hedera-sdk-js/blob/5467a470834c199ec0cc1931cd42d51ec1b5f7d7/src/EntityIdHelper.js#L253). Therefore, **it works only for non-EVM native accounts**, converting the account ID into hex values.

For example, this [`0.0.5102042`](https://hashscan.io/mainnet/account/0.0.5102042) is just a random account with a ED25519 key, and its EVM address derives from the account ID; it is `0x00000000000000000000000000000000004dd9da`, and that can be computed offline.

In your case, you are using an EVM native account instead, so the address is derived from the public key, not the account ID, so the `toSolidityAddress()` function cannot be used because it will return an incorrect value.

About the behavior change - it was working before, but now it is not - can be due to using a non-EVM native account the first time. In that case, the `toSolidityAddress()` incompatibility didn't emerge.

Comment: Great explanation @Giuseppe. Thank you so much. I will add another answer with an updated code snippet with a working example, but I have marked your answer as the right one. 

I think Hedera should make the distinction very clear between when to use EVM or non-EVM addresses and where exactly to use them, so there is no confusion.